# Sum by factor client id

Tags: r, dataframe

I have quite a tricky question (or at least for me) today. I have a Data Frame where I want so sum the number of clients from the same location if that makes sense. Each client has a unique ID but they might buy several products so the ID will appear again.

Ill give you an example so is easier. This is the shortened DF:

```
ID            LOC
 1 "Buenos Aires"
 1 "Buenos Aires"
 2     "Santa fe"
 3      "Mendoza"
 4      "Mendoza"
 4      "Mendoza"
 5      "Neuquen"
 6      "Neuquen"
 7      "Neuquen"
```

And I want to transform that DF into something that will look like this:

```
 LOC           Value
 Buenos Aires  1
 Santa fe      1
 Mendoza       2
 Neuquen       3
```

So all `LOC` ("locations") that have a different `id` number are sumed with each other so I can know the number of clients within each location.

Comment: This seems pretty basic. Did you do any searching?

Comment: Try: as.data.frame(table( DF$LOC )) or tapply(DF$LOC, DF$LOC, length)

Comment: @42- that will include an extra Buenos Aires, as two of them have the same `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after unique `ids` for each `LOC`, and then you want to count each one, so use a `table` around a `unique`

```
table(unique(d)$LOC)
# Buenos Aires      Mendoza      Neuquen     Santa fe 
#           1            2            3            1 

# and for a data.frame: 
# as.data.frame(table(unique(d)$LOC))
#           Var1 Freq
# 1 Buenos Aires    1
# 2      Mendoza    2
# 3      Neuquen    3
# 4     Santa fe    1
```

---

Data (thanks @gung)

```
d <- read.table(text='ID          LOC
 1 "Buenos Aires"
                                1 "Buenos Aires"
                                2     "Santa fe"
                                3      "Mendoza"
                                4      "Mendoza"
                                4      "Mendoza"
                                5      "Neuquen"
                                6      "Neuquen"
                                7      "Neuquen"', header=T)
```

Comment: And similarly, `aggregate(cbind(Value=ID) ~ LOC, data=unique(d), FUN=length)` could do it, but that is pretty much identical in both logic and result.

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- read.table(text='ID          LOC
 1 "Buenos Aires"
 1 "Buenos Aires"
 2     "Santa fe"
 3      "Mendoza"
 4      "Mendoza"
 4      "Mendoza"
 5      "Neuquen"
 6      "Neuquen"
 7      "Neuquen"', header=T)

ds <- split(d, f=d$LOC)
sapply(ds, FUN=function(x){ length(table(x$ID)) })
# Buenos Aires      Mendoza      Neuquen     Santa fe 
#            1            2            3            1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Value=uniqueN(ID)), by = LOC]
#            LOC Value
#1: Buenos Aires     1
#2:     Santa fe     1
#3:      Mendoza     2
#4:      Neuquen     3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DF <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7),LOC=c("Buenos Aires","Buenos Aires","Santa fe",
  rep("Mendoza",3),rep("Neuquen",3)),stringsAsFactors = F)

for(i in unique(DF$LOC)){
  DF$val[DF$LOC==i] <- length(unique(DF$ID[DF$LOC==i]))
}

DF <-DF[!duplicated(DF$LOC),]

print(DF)

  ID          LOC val
1  1 Buenos Aires   1
3  2     Santa fe   1
4  3      Mendoza   2
7  5      Neuquen   3
```